# ReactJS Not Found

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The homepage loads ok in my ReactJSAPP, but when I click on any link it throws the following error. Since I am new to ReactJS, I am not sure which file I should check and fix this issue. Nodejs is working on port `4407`

**Folder Structure**

[image]

```
Not Found
404
Error: Not Found
    at /home/abc/public_html/ReactNode/app.js:46:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/abc/public_html/ReactNodeNew/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4007",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4007;
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mysql = require("mysql");
//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'nodejs',
        password : '333365,',
        database : 'nodejs',
        port     : '3306'
    });
    res.locals.connection.connect();
    next();
});

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build')));

app.use('/api', index);
app.use('/api/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/frontend/build/index.html'))
})
var http = require('http');
module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Do you mind adding React JS's `index.js` also? And `routes/index.js` too.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman added /routes/index.js There is no index.js in the root here is the folder/file structure http://prntscr.com/nmijrp

Comment: Have you started both the servers? The React one and your Node one? Are you starting both manually one by one or is it done by a combinator?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman one by one, started both.